# In between Ex Post Facto and Ex Ante

Tags: idiom

I'm looking for Latin for "at the time of the event". So if ex ante is before the event and ex post facto is after the event, is there an equivalent for at the time of the event?

Comment: Are you looking for specifically if there was Roman legal terminology that is analogous to these terms (since these come from Roman legal language) or are you ok with coining a neologism if nothing already is comparable?

Comment: Note that while *ante* and *post* are real words, *ex ante* and *ex post* are not actual Latin.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel I thought the same at first, but both are amply attested, the former in Justinian's Digest ([ex post fact*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=ex%20post%20fact)) and the latter in Cicero ([ex ante fact*](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=ex%20ante%20fact)).

Comment: @cmw I was obviously not suggesting the words *ex ante* cannot stand in this order in Latin. All three Cicero loci refer to someone's *ante facta (aut dicta)* = previous actions (and statements). You can say *ex ante factis lucet XYZ* but not *ex ante videtur XYZ*.